# How can I run a method at the end of a file from a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, rack

I have a gem (e.g. `mygem`) and as is normal, I add `mygem` to a file by putting `require "mygem"` at the top. What if I have a method in `mygem` called `finish_jobs` and I want it to run in the following location:

```
require "mygem"
# code, code code
finish_jobs
```

How would I do that without forcing the user to add the method every time they use the gem?

Specifically, what I am trying to do is write a server app (with rack) and I need the methods in the body of the file to be processed before the server is started.

Comment: Is "code code code" where you're starting your server?

Comment: `code code code` would be were I am setting various parts of my server which must be setup before I start running it.

Comment: I feel like you should write a config.rb that does what you need and refactor that.

Comment: Arbitrarily running code like this on exit is considered extremely rude for a gem to do *unless* you've got a very specific use case and the user of your library is fully expecting it. The one example I can think of is `test/unit` where it runs tests by default just by requiring the library.

Comment: @thesecretmaster how do you start the server? Maybe you could add a rack middleware in your gem that is automatically applied?

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible.

Why not just add the code directly into the Gem (since it sounds like it is under your control and is not an external dependency)?

```
module MyGem
  def printSomething
    p 2 + 2
  end

  module_function :printSomething
  printSomething()
  # => 4
end
```

If this isn't what you had in mind, let me know and I can update the solution.

Also, see [Kernel#at_exit](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit)
A more explanatory guide on [Kernel#at_exit](http://best-ruby.com/tricks/at-exit-method.html)

Comment: another possibility would be to check for a return from `main` or whatever the global object is (where the code is written) - though be aware that its name would change depending on where it is run from (irb, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do what you're describing.

One workaround would be to provide an API which accepts a block. This approach allows you to run code *after* the user's setup without exposing implementation details to them.

A user could call your library method, providing a block to set up their server:

```
require "mygem" 

MyGem.code_code_code {
  # user's code goes here
}
```

Then, your library code would:

- Accept the block
- Call some library code

Here's an example implementation:

```
module MyGem  
  # Run some user-provided code by `yield`-ing the block 
  # Then run the gem's finalizer 
  def self.code_code_code
    # Execute the block: 
    yield 
    # Finalize:
    finish_jobs
  end 
end
```

This way, you can accept code from the user but still control setup and finalization.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Would there be a way to do this if I have multiple block methods, then after the code is executed then run my function?